# vb.net - how do I embed a file to run during execution?

Tags: vb.net, resources, publish

Using VS2010 Professional and vb.net in a winforms project.

I am trying to include a .bat file in my project so that the application can have access to it and 
run it after the user installs my build.

I have brought the file into my resources.
I have set its properties to

```
"Build Action: Embedded Resource"
 and 
"Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always"
```

In my code I have:

```
strPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
strPath = Right(strPath, strPath.Length - 6)

  Dim myProcess As New Process()
  Try  
     myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
     myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = strPath & "\resources\myfile.bat"
     myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
     myProcess.Start()
     myProcess.WaitForExit()
  Catch e As Exception
      MessageBox.Show(e.Message)
  End Try
```

It works for me when I run it, but after I build it, I do not see the .bat file anywhere in the build and it does not work on any other machine.

Why does the file not get copied with my build?

Thanks.

Comment: A batch file(.bat) is basically a text file.  You could embed the file with a .txt extension through the resource designer then make a temporary copy on the hard drive as a .bat file, and run it from there.

Comment: but how do I make a temp copy and run it?

Answer (score 0):

> A batch file(.bat) is basically a text file. You could embed the file
>   with a .txt extension through the resource designer then make a
>   temporary copy on the hard drive as a .bat file, and run it from
>   there.
>
> but how do I make a temp copy and run it?

The file is stored as a long string simply write the string to a file with a .bat extension.  For instance adding a file called "test.txt" through the Resources tab in the project properties, means you can write it like this:

```
IO.File.WriteAllText("test.bat", My.Resources.test)
```

Comment: OK, I've got that working, but how do I send a parameter to the .bat file using this method?

Comment: Actually, It still only works on my machine. I can't get the file to be created on another machine.

Comment: Use the process class to run the file.  It allows passing arguments.  Make sure you have permission to run the file and permission to run it from the folder you're using.  On a side note, most .bat files are relatively short and do simple things.  It shouldn't be that difficult to make a function(s) to do the same things.